# Xamarin : Move accessibility focus to span elements inside the label

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, accessibility

I have a very long text and it it has "terms and conditions" and "privacy policy" when clicked it opens a web view.
I have used Label.FormattedText and Span elements for this.

When talkback is turned on the focus is on the label, but user should be able to move the focus to terms and conditions and privacy policy text.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set focus on label, use code like:

```
Label mylabel=new Label();
mylabel.Focus();
```